# Is code like this a "train wreck" (in violation of Law of Demeter)?

Tags: language-agnostic, clean-code

Browsing through some code I've written, I came across the following construct which got me thinking. At a first glance, it seems clean enough. Yes, in the actual code the `getLocation()` method has a slightly more specific name which better describes exactly which location it gets.

```
service.setLocation(this.configuration.getLocation().toString());
```

In this case, `service` is an instance variable of a known type, declared within the method. `this.configuration` comes from being passed in to the class constructor, and is an instance of a class implementing a specific interface (which mandates a public `getLocation()` method). Hence, the return type of the expression `this.configuration.getLocation()` is known; specifically in this case, it is a `java.net.URL`, whereas `service.setLocation()` wants a `String`. Since the two types String and URL are not directly compatible, *some* sort of conversion is required to fit the square peg in the round hole.

**However**, according to the Law of Demeter as cited in *Clean Code*, a method *f* in class *C* should only call methods on *C*, objects created by or passed as arguments to *f*, and objects held in instance variables of *C*. Anything beyond that (the final `toString()` in my particular case above, unless you consider a temporary object created as a result of the method invocation itself, in which case the whole Law seems to be moot) is disallowed.

Is there a valid reasoning why a call like the above, given the constraints listed, should be discouraged or even disallowed? Or am I just being overly nitpicky?

If I were to implement a method `URLToString()` which simply calls `toString()` on a `URL` object (such as that returned by `getLocation()`) passed to it as a parameter, and returns the result, I could wrap the `getLocation()` call in it to achieve exactly the same result; effectively, I would just move the conversion one step outward. Would that somehow make it acceptable? (It *seems* to me, intuitively, that it should not make any difference either way, since all that does is move things around a little. However, going by the letter of the Law of Demeter as cited, it would be acceptable, since I would then be operating directly on a parameter to a function.)

Would it make any difference if this was about something slightly more exotic than calling `toString()` on a standard type?

When answering, do keep in mind that altering the behavior or API of the type that the `service` variable is of is not practical. Also, for the sake of argument, let's say that altering the return type of `getLocation()` is also impractical.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The problem here *is* the signature of `setLocation`. It's [**stringly typed**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html).

To elaborate: Why would it expect `String`? A `String` represents *any kind of textual data*. It can potentially be anything but a valid location.

In fact, this poses a question: what is a location? How do *I* know without looking into your code? If it were a `URL` than I would know a lot more about what this method expects.
Maybe it would make more sense for it to be a custom class `Location`. Ok, I wouldn't know at first, what that is, but at some point (probably before writing `this.configuration.getLocation()` I would take a minute to figure out what it is this method returns).
Granted, in both cases I need to look some place else to understand, what is expected. However in the latter case, if I understand, what a `Location` is, I can use your API, in the former case, if I understand, what a `String` is (which can be expected), I still don't know what your API expects.

In the unlikely scenario, that a location is *any kind of textual data* I would reinterpret this to *any kind of data, that has a textual representation*. Given the fact, that `Object` has a `toString` method, you could go with that, although this demands quite a leap of faith from the clients of your code.

Also you should consider, that this is Java you're talking about, which has very few features by design. That's what's forcing you to actually call the `toString` at the end.
If you take C# for example, which is also statically typed, then you would actually be able to omit that call by [defining behavior for an implicit cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).
In dynamically typed languages, such as Objective-C, you don't really need the conversion either, because as long as the value behaves like a string, everybody is happy.

One could argue, that the last call to `toString` is less a call, than actually just noise generated by Java's demand for explicitness. You're calling a method, that *any* Java object has, therefore you do not actually encode any knowledge about a "distant unit" and thereby don't violate the Principle of Least Knowledge. There is no way, no matter what `getLocation` returns, that it doesn't have a `toString` method.

But please, do not use strings, unless they are really the most natural choice (or unless you're using a language, that doesn't even have enums ... been there).

Comment: I would tend to agree with you, but he already said he cannot modify the service API.

Comment: @jhocking: He didn't say he can't. He said it's impractical. I disagree. Trying to apply best practices to code that works around flaws in API design really only makes sense if such workarounds are the only possible option. However here setting the API straight is the best option. Removing deficiencies is always preferable to working around them.

Comment: well +1 anyway for "is less a call than actually just noise generated by Java's demand for explicitness"

Comment: agreed, the core issue is that location is not a string, it needs to be a Location (or some other thingie representing a location idea).

Comment: I'd give this +1 even if just for "stringly typed". In my code, I try to pass types that express meaning/intent as much as possible, but when working with third-party libraries and APIs, sometimes you are kind of stuck using what the authors of that API decided on. And IIRC, a location *can* indeed be "any kind of textual data", but for the implementation I am working on, a non-URL location is totally meaningless.

Comment: The question, however, is not so much about this specific case as it is about where one should draw the line. Notice that toward the end of the question, I ask *Would it make any difference if this was about something slightly more exotic than calling `toString()` on a standard type?*

Comment: As for changing the API; this is computer software, so it is virtually always *possible* to change things. (If nothing else you can always write an abstraction layer.) However, sometimes doing so involves way too much effort both short- and long-term to be justifiable. Then, it might be perfectly possible to make such changes, but still impractical.

Comment: "stringly typed" is bad enough. But if I have methods getLocation and setLocation, the result of getLocation should be immediately usable as a parameter for setLocation, without any change.

Answer (score 21):

Demeter's law is a design guideline, not a law to be followed religiously.

If you feel that your classes are enough decoupled than there's nothing wrong with the line `this.configuration.getLocation()` especially if, as you say, it is impractical to change other parts of the API.

I'm pretty sure that the client will be perfectly happy even if you make the Demeter's Law to pieces, as long as you deliver what he wants and on time. Which is not an excuse to make bad software, but a reminder to be pragmatic when developing software.

Comment: Since `this.configuration` is an instance variable of a type of a known interface, calling a method on it that is defined by that interface seems fine even according to a strict interpretation. Yes, I know that it's a guideline, just like KISS, SOLID, YAGNI and so on. There are very few if indeed any "laws" (in the legal sense) in general software development.

Comment: +1 for being pragmatic ;-)

Comment: I don't think the Law of Dementer should even apply in a case like this--configuration is basically a container.  In every API I have ever worked with looking inside containers is normal and expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of not writing code like this is what if `this.configuration.getLocation()` returns null?  It depends on your surrounding code and target audience using this code.  But as Marco say - Demeter's law is a rule of thumb - it's good to follow, but don't break your back doing so unnecessarily.

Comment: If `this.configuration.getLocation()` would return null, then we either (a) most likely never would have got that far, or (b) something catastrophic has happened in the interim, in which case I would *want* the code to fail. So while this is definitely a valid point in general, in this particular case it's fairly safe to say that it does not apply. Also, surrounding all this and much more is an exception handler specifically designed to deal with that sort of unexpected failures.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly following the Law of Demeter would mean you should implement a method in the configuration object like:

```
function getLocationAsString() {
  return getLocation().toString();
}
```

but personally I wouldn't bother because this is such a small situation, and anyway your hands are kinda tied because of the API you can't change. Programming rules are about what you should do when you have a choice, but sometimes you don't have a choice.

Comment: That's the same suggested here: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TrainWreck "Create a method which represents the desired behavior and tells the client what to do. This follows the "tell, don't ask" principle. "